# Laravel5 vsmoraes/pdf-laravel5 errors

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5

I'm using [this](https://github.com/vsmoraes/pdf-laravel5) library.So i have this errors when i download

> Undefined variable: cv_info

Here is my controller

```
public function downloadPDF()
    {
        $url=Input::get('url');
        $url=explode('/', $url);
        $cv_id = substr($url[4], 0, -13);
        $name=Auth::user()->username;
        $cv_info=CV::where('id','=',$cv_id)->first();
        $html = view('ui.userinfo.viewCV',$cv_info)->render();

        return $this->pdf
        ->load($html)
        ->show();
    }
```

I'm already pass the $cv_info to view why i have this erros.Thanks for help

> $html = view('ui.userinfo.viewCV',$cv_info)->render();

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing it correctly.

```
$html = view('ui.userinfo.viewCV')->with('cv_info', $cv_info);
```

Or you could use

```
$html = view('ui.userinfo.viewCV', ['cv_info' => $cv_info])->render();
```

Comment: -I'm  using the first method i will get this errors  
FatalErrorException in UserController.php line 190:
Call to a member function render() on string 
-The second method i will get this errors  ErrorException in frame_decorator.cls.php line 573:
DOMNode::cloneNode(): ID mainArea already defined

Comment: Apparently you can't call `render` after `with` which is strange behavior but you shouldn't need it anyway.  It looks like it worked and now you have an error elsewhere.